# SQL SERVER connection from another server on the network

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, asp-classic, odbc

I'm having trouble connecting to a database on another server. I have setup the DSN which in testing works perfect. However when running the asp script with the follwing code:

```
<%
Dim rsGetInvoiceContact
Dim rsGetInvoiceContact_numRows

Set rsGetInvoiceContact = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsGetInvoiceContact.ActiveConnection = MM_conn_to_EFACs_STRING_ap
rsGetInvoiceContact.Source = "SELECT *   from "& ActinicPersons &" p  WHERE p.[Contact ID] = " + Replace(rsGetInvoiceContact__vInvoiceID, "'", "''") + "" 
rsGetInvoiceContact.CursorType = 0
rsGetInvoiceContact.CursorLocation = 2
rsGetInvoiceContact.LockType = 1
rsGetInvoiceContact.Open()

rsGetInvoiceContact_numRows = 0
%>
```

With the below connection string:

```
Dim MM_conn_to_EFACs_STRING_ap
MM_conn_to_EFACs_STRING_ap = "dsn=DSNefacsdb2;uid=IUSR_RFS01;pwd=Splendid01;"
```

The error show after running the script:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

/Sales/order_entry.asp, line 55
```

When running the script against the local database it works as I want it, I have adjusted all the permissions on the other database for the user IUSR_RFS01, but still no joy! :(

Answer (score 0):

The iusr is not what you want but the user acct that connects to SQL server.

Actually check if the firewall on the server is turned on? You might have to allow/configure certain ports on the firewall before it works.

Or check that the SQL server allows remote connections to it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I currently use the administrator account to goin to the server, would I put that in the connection string? Ports seem to be all permitted at the moment. Remote desktop is allowed.

Comment: Try it by using the sa account to see if you can access the database.

Comment: No joy with the sa account, any other ideas?